# Remove Host from Foreman

Tags: foreman, puppet-foreman

In Foreman 1.12 I deleted a VM from the VMware web client, but cannot delete its record from foreman.

I got the below error:

```
Error: Failed to destroy a compute VMware (VMware) instance
*************: ERF56-4248 [Foreman::FingerprintException]: The remote system presented a public key with hash *********** but we're expecting a different hash. If you are sure the remote system is authentic, go to the compute resource edit page, press the 'Test Connection' or 'Load Datacenters' button and submit
```

So, how can I delete host from the foreman?

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, verify connection to Compute Resource by going through

compute resource >> edit CR >> press the 'Test Connection' or 'Load Datacenters' button and submit

And check if you have copied the Foreman Public Key(/usr/share/foreman/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) to the Compute Resouce.

[2] Try following commands.

```
foreman-rake console
Host.find_by_name("host.example.test").destroy
```